# cant upload image to Ghost CMS

Tags: python, ghost-blog

anybody know to upload image using python to Ghost CMS?

```
url = "https://analisa.ifxid.trade/ghost/api/v3/admin/images/upload/"
headers = {'Authorization': 'Ghost {}'.format(token.decode()),'Content-Type': 'form-data;'}
files = {'file':('ifxb.png', open('ifxb.png', 'rb'))}
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
print(r.text)
```

end up

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Please select an image.","context":null,"type":"ValidationError","details":null,"property":null,"help":null,"code":null,"id":"e114da60-d7c9-11ea-972e-97f9c75664c6"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Postman gave me the answer, the content-type for the picture was missing on files dict. It should work now.

```
url = "https://analisa.ifxid.trade/ghost/api/v3/admin/images/upload/"
headers = {'Authorization': 'Ghost {}'.format(token.decode()),'Content-Type': 'form-data;'}
files = {'file':('ifxb.png', open('ifxb.png', 'rb'), 'image/png')}
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
print(r.text)
```